# Conditional Probability Problem Find P{$X_{i}=i|X_{1}+X_{2}=n$}

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ be independent geometric random variables having the same parameter p.

Find P{$X_{i}=i|X_{1}+X_{2}=n$}.

P{$X_{i}=i|X_{1}+X_{2}=n$} = ${P({X_{i}=i,X_{1}+X_{2}=n})\over P({X_{1}+X_{2}=n})}$ = ${P({X_{i}=I,X_{2}=n - i})\over P({X_{1}+X_{2}=n})}$ = ${p(1-p)^{i - 1}p(1-p)^{n - i - 1}\over {\binom{n-1}{1}}p(1-p)^{n - 2}p}$ = ${1\over {n - 1}}$

That is the solution from the book. I was able to get up to the numerator of ${p(1-p)^{i - 1}p(1-p)^{n - i - 1}\over {\binom{n-1}{1}}p(1-p)^{n - 2}p}$.

Why is ${{\binom{n-1}{1}}p(1-p)^{n - 2}p}$ the correct denominator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:  The denominator is a sum from $i=1$ to $n-1$ of terms of the shape $\Pr(X_1=i)\Pr(X_2=n-i)$. Each term simplifies to $p^2(1-p)^{n-2}$, just like the top did.  There are $n-1=\binom{n-1}{1}$ terms.

Another way: The sum of the two geometrics $X_1$ and $X_2$ has *negative binomial* distribution. We want the probability of exactly one success in the first $n-1$ trials, followed by a success. The probability of $1$ success in the first $n-1$ trials is $\binom{n-1}{1}p(1-p)^{n-2}$.

Comment: How do I know I am looking for 1 success? My book has P(X=n) = $\binom{n-1}{r-1} p^{r-1}(1-p)^{n-r}$ , where n = r, r+1, ... and r is number of successes, as the formula for a negative binomial random variable.

Comment: Think of $X_1$ as the number of trials until the first success, and of $X_2$ as the number of trials from the first success to the second. Then $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent geometric with the same parameter $p$. The probability that $X_1+X_2=n$ is the probability that the **second** success occurs on the $n$-th trial. So we want exactly one success in the first $n-1$, and success on the $n$-th. Probability $\binom{n-1}{1}p(1-p)^{n-2}p$. If we want waiting time until $r$-th success, we can use the same reasoning.   (More)

Comment: The formula you quote is almost what I wrote except there is a $p^{r-1}$ instead of the correct $p^r$.  Sometimes formulas for the geometric, negative binomial have to be read carefully. As you will see from Wikipedia, some people use a different notion of geometric, not number of trials but number of failures until the first success.

Comment: Ok I understand now. Thanks for the help

Comment: You are welcome. The first way I described uses less machinery, particularly since you already basically did all the work already when you computed the numerator. So ultimately we get almost total cancellation, the conditional probability is discrete uniform, with probability (weight) $\frac{1}{n-1}$ at the points $1$ to $n-1$.